# Add colum that sums up values until this row

Tags: r, sum, dataframe

Assume I have a dataframe `df` with one column namely `time`. Now, I'd like to add a new column to the dataframe `accumulated` as seen below, that sums up the values from `df.time` for each row.

```
    time     accumulated
1   10       10
2   12       22
3   14       36
4   6        42
```

A quick hint would be really nice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For these simple tasks there is usually a build-in function. Of course, knowing what the mathematical operation is called helps finding these functions. You want the cumulative sum.

```
df <- data.frame(time=c(10,12,14,6))

df$accumulated <- cumsum(df$time)

#  time accumulated
#1   10          10
#2   12          22
#3   14          36
#4    6          42
```